# My Jquery change is not working in Mobile

Tags: jquery

My Jquery is not working on mobile, and it is working fine on desktop.

**My Code:**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('SP');
    jQuery('#form-field-field_d280ad3').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    jQuery('#form-field-time_for_mobile').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 


    jQuery('#form-field-select_location').change(function(){

     console.log('SP 2');
     jQuery('#form-field-field_d280ad3').attr("disabled", "disabled");
     jQuery('#form-field-time_for_mobile').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 

        if(jQuery(this).val() == 'Northwest Indiana Mobile') {
            console.log('SP 3');                

            jQuery('#form-field-time_for_mobile').removeAttr("disabled");
            jQuery("#form-field-time_for_mobile").attr("required", "true");
            jQuery("#form-field-field_d280ad3").removeAttr("required");
            jQuery('#form-field-field_d280ad3').val('');
        } else {
            console.log('SP 4'); 

            jQuery('#form-field-field_d280ad3').removeAttr("disabled");
            jQuery("#form-field-time_for_mobile").removeAttr("required");
            jQuery("#form-field-field_d280ad3").attr("required", "true");
            jQuery('#form-field-time_for_mobile').val('');
        } 
    });
});

</script>
```

In desktop, the field is not disabled on selecting the drop-down but in mobile the field is disabled on selecting the value from drop-down.

It is not printing `console.log('SP 3')`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You want it to be disabled or no? You disabled both #form-field-field_d280ad3 and #form-field-time_for_mobile. What is your expected behavior?

Comment: @EvikGhazarian On Value select, if(jQuery(this).val() == 'Northwest Indiana Mobile'), I am removing disabled on one and other will be disabled but in mobile this is not working.

Comment: @GuyIncognito. Yes, It is printing the correct values and now it is printing console values also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
let me=this;
if(jQuery(me).val() == 'Northwest Indiana Mobile') {
```

This will work both in Desktop and Mobile and this will print SP 3 and SP 4.

And you should try to `console.log( jQuery(this).val() );`. I am sure the values are coming and you can add the condition accordingly.

Hope this will solve your  problem.